# Docky Pidgin helper is enabled but not working

Tags: docky, pidgin

I've enabled Pidgin helper in Docky. But it really doesn't do anything.. 
There's no difference at all whether it's enabled or not.. 
I really don't know why but it doesn't do what it should like in the screenshot in it's page

http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=Pidgin_control_Helper

I tried to debug Docky:

```
[Info  15:01:19.468] Docky version: 2.2.0 bzr docky r1817 ppa
[Info  15:01:19.493] Kernel version: 2.6.35.30
[Info  15:01:19.497] CLR version: 2.0.50727.1433
[Debug 15:01:20.023] [UserArgs] BufferTime = 10
[Debug 15:01:20.024] [UserArgs] MaxSize = 2147483647
[Debug 15:01:20.024] [UserArgs] NetbookMode = False
[Debug 15:01:20.024] [UserArgs] NoPollCursor = False
[Debug 15:01:20.071] [SystemService] Using org.freedesktop.UPower for battery information
[Info  15:01:20.125] [ThemeService] Setting theme: HUD
[Debug 15:01:20.158] [DesktopItemService] Loading remap file '/usr/share/docky/remaps.ini'.
[Debug 15:01:20.172] [DesktopItemService] Remapping 'Picasa3.exe' to 'picasa'.
[Debug 15:01:20.172] [DesktopItemService] Remapping 'nbexec' to 'netbeans'.
[Debug 15:01:20.172] [DesktopItemService] Remapping 'deja-dup-preferences' to 'deja-dup'.
[Debug 15:01:20.172] [DesktopItemService] Remapping 'VirtualBox' to 'virtualbox'.
[Warn  15:01:20.173] [DesktopItemService] Could not find remap file '/home/rafael/.local/share/docky/remaps.ini'!
[Debug 15:01:20.177] [DesktopItemService] Loading desktop item cache '/home/rafael/.cache/docky/docky.desktop.en_US.utf8.cache'.
[Info  15:01:20.523] [DockServices] Dock services initialized.
[Debug 15:01:20.557] [DBusManager] DBus Registered: org.gnome.Docky
[Debug 15:01:20.565] [DBusManager] DBus Registered: net.launchpad.DockManager
[Debug 15:01:20.960] [PluginManager] Plugin manager initialized.
[Debug 15:01:20.982] [PluginManager] Processing config file for "Battery Monitor".
[Debug 15:01:21.013] [PluginManager] Processing config file for "Bookmarks".
[Debug 15:01:21.015] [PluginManager] Processing config file for "CPU Monitor".
[Debug 15:01:21.016] [PluginManager] Processing config file for "Clippy".
[Debug 15:01:21.018] [PluginManager] Processing config file for "Clock".
[Debug 15:01:21.023] [PluginManager] Processing config file for "Desktop".
[Debug 15:01:21.024] [PluginManager] Processing config file for "Gmail".
[Debug 15:01:21.025] [PluginManager] Processing config file for "Mounter".
[Debug 15:01:21.027] [PluginManager] Processing config file for "NPR".
[Debug 15:01:21.028] [PluginManager] Processing config file for "Network Manager".
[Debug 15:01:21.029] [PluginManager] Processing config file for "Network Monitor".
[Debug 15:01:21.031] [PluginManager] Processing config file for "Recent Documents".
[Debug 15:01:21.032] [PluginManager] Processing config file for "Session Manager".
[Debug 15:01:21.036] [PluginManager] Processing config file for "Timer".
[Debug 15:01:21.037] [PluginManager] Processing config file for "Trash".
[Debug 15:01:21.039] [PluginManager] Processing config file for "Weather".
[Debug 15:01:21.040] [PluginManager] Processing config file for "Workspace Switcher".
[Info  15:01:21.285] [PluginManager] Loaded "Trash".
[Info  15:01:21.288] [PluginManager] Loaded "Docky.Widgets,1.0".
[Info  15:01:21.288] [PluginManager] Loaded "Clock".
[Info  15:01:22.141] [Helper] Starting pidgin_control.py
[Info  15:01:22.191] [Helper] Starting zeitgeist_menus.py
[Info  15:01:22.215] [HelperService] Helper added: /usr/share/dockmanager/scripts/banshee_control.py
[Info  15:01:22.216] [HelperService] Helper added: /usr/share/dockmanager/scripts/deluge_badge.py
[Info  15:01:22.216] [HelperService] Helper added: /usr/share/dockmanager/scripts/emesene_control.py
[Info  15:01:22.216] [HelperService] Helper added: /usr/share/dockmanager/scripts/gajim_badge.py
[Info  15:01:22.216] [HelperService] Helper added: /usr/share/dockmanager/scripts/gtg_menus.py
[Info  15:01:22.216] [HelperService] Helper added: /usr/share/dockmanager/scripts/liferea_badge.py
[Info  15:01:22.216] [HelperService] Helper added: /usr/share/dockmanager/scripts/mpd_control.py
[Info  15:01:22.217] [HelperService] Helper added: /usr/share/dockmanager/scripts/open_terminal_here.py
[Info  15:01:22.217] [HelperService] Helper added: /usr/share/dockmanager/scripts/pidgin_control.py
[Info  15:01:22.217] [HelperService] Helper added: /usr/share/dockmanager/scripts/pithos_control.py
[Info  15:01:22.217] [HelperService] Helper added: /usr/share/dockmanager/scripts/rhythmbox_control.py
[Info  15:01:22.217] [HelperService] Helper added: /usr/share/dockmanager/scripts/skype_control.py
[Info  15:01:22.217] [HelperService] Helper added: /usr/share/dockmanager/scripts/tomboy_menus.py
[Info  15:01:22.217] [HelperService] Helper added: /usr/share/dockmanager/scripts/transmission_badge.py
[Info  15:01:22.217] [HelperService] Helper added: /usr/share/dockmanager/scripts/tsclient_menus.py
[Info  15:01:22.218] [HelperService] Helper added: /usr/share/dockmanager/scripts/workrave_helper.py
[Info  15:01:22.218] [HelperService] Helper added: /usr/share/dockmanager/scripts/zeitgeist_journal.py
[Info  15:01:22.236] [HelperService] Helper added: /usr/share/dockmanager/scripts/zeitgeist_menus.py
[Info  15:01:22.285] [DrawingService] Could not find 'banshee', using fallback of 'extension'.
[Info  15:01:22.337] [DrawingService] Could not find 'deluge', using fallback of 'extension'.
[Info  15:01:22.378] [DrawingService] Could not find 'emesene', using fallback of 'extension'.
[Info  15:01:22.434] [DrawingService] Could not find 'gajim', using fallback of 'extension'.
[Info  15:01:22.465] [Helper] pidgin_control.py has exited (Code 0).
[Info  15:01:22.484] [DrawingService] Could not find 'gtg', using fallback of 'extension'.
[Info  15:01:22.509] [DrawingService] Could not find 'liferea', using fallback of 'extension'.
[Warn  15:01:22.552] [DrawingService] Error loading icon from file '/usr/share/pithos/media/icon.svg': Failed to open file '/usr/share/pithos/media/icon.svg': No such file or directory
[Debug 15:01:22.559] [DrawingService]   at Gdk.Pixbuf..ctor (System.String filename, Int32 width, Int32 height, Boolean preserve_aspect_ratio) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Docky.Services.DrawingService.IconFromFile (System.String name, Int32 width, Int32 height) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[Info  15:01:22.562] [DrawingService] Could not find '/usr/share/pithos/media/icon.svg', using fallback of 'extension'.
[Info  15:01:22.577] [DrawingService] Could not find 'rhythmbox', using fallback of 'extension'.
[Info  15:01:22.591] [DrawingService] Could not find 'skype', using fallback of 'extension'.
[Info  15:01:22.592] [Helper] zeitgeist_menus.py has exited (Code 0).
[Info  15:01:22.607] [DrawingService] Could not find 'tomboy', using fallback of 'extension'.
[Warn  15:01:22.649] [DrawingService] Error loading icon from file '/usr/share/pixmaps/workrave/workrave.xpm': Failed to open file '/usr/share/pixmaps/workrave/workrave.xpm': No such file or directory
[Debug 15:01:22.649] [DrawingService]   at Gdk.Pixbuf..ctor (System.String filename, Int32 width, Int32 height, Boolean preserve_aspect_ratio) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Docky.Services.DrawingService.IconFromFile (System.String name, Int32 width, Int32 height) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[Info  15:01:22.649] [DrawingService] Could not find '/usr/share/pixmaps/workrave/workrave.xpm', using fallback of 'extension'.
```

Anything I can do?

Comment: Installed it and it says its running...now where are the controls??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution ..

```
sudo apt-get install python-dockmanager
```

Answer (score 0):

From your debug is it clear that the helper is crashing:

`[Info  15:01:22.465] [Helper] pidgin_control.py has exited (Code 0).`

I would suggest you [report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/docky) this bug to the developers.